# Select the same column value from 3 different tables from another value with the same line of code

Tags: sql, select

How can I select the same column value from 3 different tables from another value with the same line of code?
For example I have 3 tables:

- table_one
- table_two
- table_three

All of them have the same column name lets say "date".

`table_main` has a column named `type` and the values are 1 or 2 or 3 for each row.

If `type` value is 1 than the table's name needs to be "table_one" and the "date" has to to be from that table.

I want in the same line of code to SELECT "date" from table_$num but $num needs to be from "type" so that

```
1 = one
2 = two
3 = three
```

```
SELECT table_main.id, table_main.type, table_$num.date 
FROM table_main 
   LEFT JOIN table_$num ON table_main.id = table_$num.id 
ORDER BY table_main.id ASC
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: That's a really bad design. You should only have a single table instead of three and that table should also have a column `type`

Answer (score 0):

```
select  case
             when tm.type = 1 then tab_1.date
             when tm.type = 2 then tab_2.date
             when tm.type = 3 then tab_3.date
         end
      from table_main tm
 left join table_one tab_1 
        on tm.id = tab_1.id
 left join table_two tab_2 
        on tm.id = tab_2.id
 left join table_three tab_3 
       on tm.id = tab_3.id
```

Going by your code provided, I am assuming `id` is key column, so joining on that.

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally `join` to other tables based on a type column in the first table, then use `left join` -- but include the conditions in the `on` clause:

```
select coalesce(tab_1.date, tab_2.date, tab_3.date)
from table_main tm
     table_one tab_1 
     on tm.id = tab_1.id and tm.type = 1 left join
     table_two tab_2 
     on tm.id = tab_2.id and tm.type = 2 left join
     table_three tab_3 
     on tm.id = tab_3.id and tm.type = 3
```